# How to apply a unified absolute distortion map via Python/Wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

How can I apply ImageMagick’s unified distortion map via Python/Wand?

IM documentation:
https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#distortion_maps

How it works in a shell script (IM 6.9):

```
convert "$content" \
    -resize 1700x1700\! \
    -matte "$map" \
    -compose Distort -composite "$distorted"
```

Or:

```
convert "$content" -resize 1700x1700\! -alpha set "$map" \
        -compose Distort -composite \
        "$distorted"
```

The resize brings the input image to the size of the map, as otherwise the result gets clipped.

I experimented with defining an image as `content` and using `content.compose()` or `content.composite()`, but any attempt at filling in arguments results in complaints.

Comment: Could you share your Python code and the specific complaints (error messages?) you receive?

Comment: Please show your input images and map images and your distorted output?  What is the map distortion that you are trying to do? We need this if we are going to try to implement in Pytho/OpenCV

Comment: You could just call your Imagemagick command from a subprocess call in Python!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out after seeing an example with `operator` and noticing there’s `alpha_channel`. The solution is:

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='content.png') as c,\
     Image(filename='map.png') as m:
    c.resize(1700, 1700)
    c.alpha_channel = True
    c.composite(m, operator='distort')
    c.save(filename='distorted.png')
```

Thanks to everyone who took a look.